# Will 11.04 come along with up to date GNOME Shell packages?

Tags: 11.04, gnome

Will Ubuntu 11.04 come along with up to date Gnome-Shell packages?

Comment: By 'come along with', do you mean installed by default or a package in the universe/main repositories.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it seems highly likely that GNOME Shell will not make it into the 11.04 repositories. This is because of its dependencies on the GNOME 3 stack, which won't make it into 11.04.

> There have been quite a lot of architectural changes in the rest of the GNOME stack, which we aren't adopting in Ubuntu this cycle and are necessary to make gnome-shell work properly

There is likely to be a PPA with these underlying GNOME 3 libraries and a "stable" version of GNOME Shell. GNOME 3 is due for release on April 4th, so around this time I'd start to keep a look out for this PPA.

For more details see the mailing list post [Status update on GNOME3 and natty](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-desktop/2011-January/002740.html)